# TestNG parallel test classes

Tags: java, parallel-processing, testng

I have 3 test class:

FirstTest:

```
public class FirstTest {

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("FirstTest: set up class");
    }

    @Test(groups = "FirstTest")
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("FirstTest: test1");
    }

    @Test(groups = "FirstTest")
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("FirstTest: test2");
    }

    @Test(
            groups = "FirstTest",
            dependsOnMethods = "test2"
    )
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("FirstTest: test3");
    }

    @Test(
            groups = {"FirstTest", "first:4"},
            dependsOnMethods = "test3"
    )
    public void test4() {
        System.out.println("FirstTest: test4");
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("FirstTest: tear down class");
    }
}
```

SecondTest:

```
public class SecondTest {

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("SecondTest: set up class");
    }

    @Test(groups = "SecondTest")
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("SecondTest: test1");
    }

    @Test(groups = "SecondTest")
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("SecondTest: test2");
    }

    @Test(
            dependsOnGroups = "first:4",
            groups = "SecondTest"
    )
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("SecondTest: test3");
    }

    @Test(groups = "SecondTest")
    public void test4() {
        System.out.println("SecondTest: test4");
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("SecondTest: tear down class");
    }
}
```

OtherTest:

```
public class OtherTest {

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("OtherTest: set up class");
    }

    @Test(groups = "OtherTest")
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("OtherTest: test1");
    }

    @Test(groups = "OtherTest")
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("OtherTest: test2");
    }

    @Test(groups = "OtherTest")
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("OtherTest: test3");
    }

    @Test(groups = "OtherTest")
    public void test4() {
        System.out.println("OtherTest: test4");
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("OtherTest: tear down class");
    }
}
```

I want to run them in multiple threads - One thread per class. Running tests from each class should not be interrupted to perform other tests until the entire test class will not be passed. But I have the following result(for example one thread):

TestNG.xml:

```
<suite name="Suite1" parallel="classes" thread-count="1" verbose="10">
  <test name="sample" preserve-order="true" >
    <classes>
       <class name="sample.testng.FirstTest" />
       <class name="sample.testng.SecondTest" />
       <class name="sample.testng.OtherTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Actual result:

```
sample.testng.SecondTest.setUp() 21480956
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test4() 21480956
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test1() 21480956
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test2() 21480956
sample.testng.OtherTest.setUp() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test4() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test1() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test3() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test2() 32782069
sample.testng.OtherTest.tearDown() 32782069
sample.testng.FirstTest.setUp() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test1() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test2() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test3() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test4() 2623667
sample.testng.FirstTest.tearDown() 2623667
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test3() 21480956
sample.testng.SecondTest.tearDown() 21480956
```

How do I get next result?

```
sample.testng.SecondTest.setUp() 21480956
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test4() 21480956
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test1() 21480956
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test2() 21480956
    sample.testng.SecondTest.test3() 21480956
sample.testng.SecondTest.tearDown() 21480956
sample.testng.OtherTest.setUp() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test4() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test1() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test3() 32782069
    sample.testng.OtherTest.test2() 32782069
sample.testng.OtherTest.tearDown() 32782069
sample.testng.FirstTest.setUp() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test1() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test2() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test3() 2623667
    sample.testng.FirstTest.test4() 2623667
sample.testng.FirstTest.tearDown() 2623667
```

Comment: Andrey, please clarify the question. For what you understand, you want to run the tests in different threads, but at the same time to run them sequentially. And I'll assume you know how **terribly** bad it's to make tests dependent on other tests.

Comment: Making tests dependent on each other is only discouraged for unit tests. It's very useful for all other tests. I agree with Augusto that you haven't really asked any question, though, what exactly are you trying to achieve? The output you gave here is exactly what should be expected given 'parallel="classes"'.

Comment: I have the functional tests for Selenium. I have available 3-class tests and 2 SeleniumRC (via Selenium GRID). Browser opens in setUpClass () and closes at tearDownClass ().

Comment: I want to run tests in parallel, in two streams (parallel = "classes") and I expect that a fully executed in parallel tests of the first and second class. And only then will meet the third class.

But actually, I started the first two classes (open two browsers), then run the third class with the tests, but he can not get available SeleniumRC, until the first two classes have completed execution

Comment: How do I stop jumping techniques performed between the classes of tests? To test in each class were as indivisible group.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run 1. SecondTest 2. OtherTest 3. FirstTest, as you outline in your final listing, why are you using preserve-order with classes listed as

```
   <class name="sample.testng.FirstTest" />
   <class name="sample.testng.SecondTest" />
   <class name="sample.testng.OtherTest" />
```

rather than

```
   <class name="sample.testng.SecondTest" />
   <class name="sample.testng.OtherTest" />
   <class name="sample.testng.FirstTest" />
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the thread-count=3

```
<suite name="Suite1" parallel="classes" thread-count="3" verbose="10">
  <test name="sample" preserve-order="false" >
    <classes>
       <class name="sample.testng.FirstTest" />
       <class name="sample.testng.SecondTest" />
       <class name="sample.testng.OtherTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

When you say you want to run 3 test classes in parallel, but you are passing only 1 thread to it.